# Why Gradle Wrapper JAR checksum doesn't match when generated by gradle binary from Ubuntu package

Tags: java, ubuntu, gradle, checksum, apt

[Gradle Manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#wrapper_checksum_verification) (1) suggests to verify Gradle Wrapper Jar against officially published [release checksums](https://gradle.org/release-checksums/) (2). When generating with `gradle wrapper` command and gradle being installed via `apt-get install gradle` resulting wrapper Jar's checksum doesn't match any from [(2)](https://gradle.org/release-checksums/).

Checked on Ubuntu 19.10, 18.04.3.

- (1) [Gradle Manual](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#wrapper_checksum_verification)
- (2) [Gradle Release Checksums](https://gradle.org/release-checksums/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many Linux distributions build their own distribution of Gradle, though I have no idea why. I assume this is the case for Ubuntu. And when you use a custom built distribution, it is not unreasonable to see why the checksum might end up different than the official ones.

You should only use a locally installed distribution for the first time you initialize a Gradle project. So I expect this problem will go away once you change the version for the project. For example, assume you are on a custom version 6.0 now, and you run `gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 6.0.1 --distribution-type all` twice in a row* (notice the 'w'), then it will update your project distribution of Gradle to a newer and official version. I would be surprised if the checksum didn't match after that.

Alternatively, you could also download the wrapper jar manually.

*) It is good practice to run the wrapper script twice as the wrapper scripts themselves are only updated on the second run once the newer version has been downloaded.